# Java/JavaScript graph layout library that supports node size

Tags: java, javascript, layout, graph

Could anyone please suggest a Java or JavaScript library to layout a graph. The main requirement is that it should support graph layout algorithm taking into account a node size.

I myself found [a list of Java libraries to work with graphs](http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/open-source-graph-network-visualization-in-java/) and already tried [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/), but I wasn't been able to find any graph layout implementations for JUNG that would take into account a node size. As a result some nodes happen to be too close so they're overlapping.

**P.S.:** I think it should be pointed out that I only look for a library to layout the graph (i.e. determine its nodes positions). Calculated node positions will be then transfered from the server to a client requested the layout using http.
**P.P.S.:** a JavaScript library would be as good. I already tried [arbor.js](http://arborjs.org/) and it didn't work out for me because it doesn't take into account a node size.

Answer (score 1):

is [this](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/force.html) what you are looking for?

Comment: The nodes seems to be repelling. I didn't yet have time to check it out, but I'm certainly gonna give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately there seems to be no way to extract node coordinates and specify nodes size. In this case they aren't overlapping only because of their repulsion.